# IOS Firebase , What Datatype of iOS equivalent to the field "map" ??

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have created a "map" firebase field type. Problem is when i try to query it from the firebase , the key exist but i have no idea what datatype equivalent to it.

Look like its not [[String:Any]]

```
let mydata = data.value as? [[String: Any]]

print("See it  \(mydata)")
```

result  nil

Comment: Could you add the result of printing `mydata`?

Comment: Try to print the `data.value` and see what's type it is. Or attach an output with update here.

Comment: Could you also include your database structure?!

Comment: It is unclear what Firebase database you're interacting with. Please update your question to show more of the context. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myMap = data.value as? [String: Any]
let someValue = myMap["someKey"]
```

The map is a standard `[String: Any]` dictionary; you were casting it as an array of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks , it work . I thought the result would be JSON , but im wrong ,  Firebase field type "map" equivalent to iOS [String:Any] . Thanks